# Unable to retrive WebDriver Wrapper using EventFiringWebDriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, dynamic-proxy

I have my own `CustomDriver` which extends `ChromeDriver`.

```
public CustomDriver extends ChromeDriver
```

For some need I am wrapping the CustomDriver inside the `EventFiringWebDriver` .Everything is working fine . but when I try to unwrap the underneath Driver inside the EventFiringWebDriver I get the below exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14 cannot be cast to com.test.CustomDriver.
```

Below is the Code which I am trying to Unwrap my Driver.

```
    private CustomDriver extract(EventFiringWebDriver wd) {
        return (CustomDriver)  wd.getWrappedDriver();
    }
```

Can anybody please help, Is this a bug with Selenium 2.0 or its the desired feature, If yes then how can I achive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achive it in this way. It is not important for me that what eventually EventFiringWebDriver does with the proxy Object.

```
public class EventFiringWebDriverWrapper extends EventFiringWebDriver {
    private WebDriver driver;

public EventFiringWebDriverWrapper(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    this.driver= driver;
}

@Override
public WebDriver getWrappedDriver() {
    return driver;

}
}
```

And I can extract it this way, which is good to go

```
private CustomDriver extract(EventFiringWebDriverWrapper wd) {
    return  (CustomDriver) wd.getWrappedDriver();
 }
```

Comment: I'm glad you have it resolved. The only thing you may need to consider is a threading issue: make sure you're not using a driver you got this way in multiple threads. That's the reason the actualy put proxy here - to control referring thread id.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have a Manager which has a hook on Threadlocal on this so I can be rest assured of handling multiple threads

Answer (score 1):

issue fixed by [selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6414) . Above mentioned answers is just work around. please refer the fix from selenium.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Selenium uses JDK dynamic proxies in this case. This proxy is wrapped aroung your implementation, effectively hiding it. You can try `Proxy.isProxyClass(wd)` to check, if this is true. In general there is no way to exctract a delegate from a proxy, but you can try to look in `InvocatioinHandler` obtained by `Proxy.getInvocationHandler(wd)`, chances are that your `CustomDriver` can be extracted from there:

```
private CustomDriver extract(EventFiringWebDriver wd) {
    if (Proxy.isCroxyClass(wd)){
       InvocationHandler ih = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(wd);
       // examine ih with debugger or reflection, your CustomDriver is likely to be somewhere inside
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , let me check and revert back.

Comment: Yes I am able to examine but I am unable to find how to retrive it? can I do it if I extend the EventFiringWebDriver.